# Read a particular data corresponding to a row & column in CSV

Tags: java, csv, selenium, automation

I need some help. I want to implement a code where-in I wish to read data from a csv file.

***Sample CSV file (details.csv) :***

id,name,age

1,bh,23

2,nit,24

I want to create such a method in java to read this CSV that I pass the sheetname, columnname and rowname as parameters. Where ever there is a match of this combination, the corresponding data is picked.

***Example :- I want to pass details.csv,name & 1. I should get the output as bh.***

Could you please help me with this?

I tried with the following code but it is returning null value :-

```
public static String searchCsvLine(String filename, String searchString, String rowname) throws IOException {
    String resultRow = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    String line;

        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");

        if(values.equals(searchString)) {
            resultRow = line;
            break;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return resultRow;
}
```

Comment: `values.equals(searchString)` - you are comparing an array with a String

Comment: could you help me to resolve this

Comment: @BhoomikaDatta -    You can use if condition like this, considering name is at fixed index on each line
`if(values[1].equals(searchString)){  resultRow = line; break;  }`

Comment: It still returns a null value

Comment: Convert array to list like by List<String> list = Arrays.asList(values); then use list.contains(searchString) instead

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the first line of csv file to get column names.

```
public class Test {

    public static String searchCsvLine(String filename, String columnName, String rowName) throws IOException {
        String resultRow = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        // parse first line as column names
        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] columns = line.split(",");
        int columnIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (columnName.equals(columns[i])) {
                columnIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // read lines to match row
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            if (rowName.equals(values[0])) {
                // return value at columnIndex
                resultRow = values[columnIndex];
                break;
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return resultRow;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String name = searchCsvLine("details.cvs", "name", "1");
        System.out.println("name is " + name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
public static String searchCsvLine(String filename, String searchString,String rowname) throws IOException {
        String resultRow = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        int searchStringIndex=0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
//get index of searchString
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                if(values[i].equalsIgnoreCase(searchString)){
                    searchStringIndex=i;
                    break;
                }
            }
//get required rowname  
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(rowname); i++) {
                line=br.readLine();
            }
//split the line found by rowname and get value as per searchString index (given column)    
            values = line.split(",");
            resultRow=values[searchStringIndex];
            break;
        }

        br.close();
        System.out.println(resultRow);
        return resultRow;
    }
}
```